# Why the type of dynamic variable is not like the return type of the method at run time?

Tags: c#, dynamic

I have the following C# code :

```
public class A
{
    public static A amethod()
    {
        return new C()
    }

}

public class C : A
{        
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    dynamic obj1 = A.amethod()
}
```

Why the type of `obj1` is C and not A after running the application ?

Comment: but the return type of the method is A , if i use var obj1 = A.method() the obj1's type will be A.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `dynamic`.  `typeof` will get the instantiated type of an object reference.  Since you are creating a new `C` that's its type.

Comment: Yes, a `C` is an `A` so it is returning an `A`. But if you are looking at it in the runtime, you are going to see the actual type. Which is a `C`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is the type of `obj1` `C` and not `A` after running the application?

For the same reason why the type of `obj1` is `C` when you make this modification:

```
A obj1 = A.amethod();
```

While the statically known type of `obj1` is `A`, its runtime type is `C`, because that is what `amethod()` returns.

When you change the type of `obj1` to `dynamic`, the value assigned to it remains `C`. However, the compiler promises not to bother you with any static type checking, so if you then do this

```
obj1.SomeMethod();
```

the code would compile, but it would break at runtime unless you change `C` to implement `SomeMethod()`.

Comment: Yep.  `dynamic` was a red herring here.  Makes this seem more mysterious than it is.

Comment: The type of object in memory is C that's obvious but what i mean is the object reference variable without using dynamic is A and C when using dynamic ...that's the difference

Comment: @KhalilLazhar The object reference variable has two types, which may or may not be the same. One type is the static type; the other type is the runtime type. When you declare a variable as `A obj1`, you give it a static type of `A`. When you declare a variable as `dynamic obj1`, you give it a static type of `System.Object` (i.e. no specific type). The runtime type in both cases is determined by the value you assign. If you assign `new C()` to it, the runtime type will be `C` in both cases.